# Convert date range object into ISO-8601 format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using [this react based](https://github.com/Kiarash-Z/react-modern-calendar-datepicker) date range picker. It gives me a `setSelectedDayRange` as an object of `from` and `to` like this

```
from: {day: 3, month: 8, year: 2020}
to: {day: 8, month: 8, year: 2020}
```

I need to convert the above into the `ISO-8601 format`. Since I already have moment.js installed in my project, I was hoping to utilize it.

The problem is

1. if I try to do it like

   ```
       setSelectedDayRange = moment();
       let convertedDate = moment().toISOString();
       console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDate);
   ```

It only converts the `to` date.

2. if I try to do it like

   ```
        let convertedDate = moment(setSelectedDayRange).toISOString();
        console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDate);
   ```

It ends up converting `currentDate-1`

```
handleDatePickerChange = (setSelectedDayRange) => {
        console.log("initializing handleDatePickerChange()");
        console.log("setSelectedDayRange", setSelectedDayRange);
        // TODO
        // convert the dates
        
        setSelectedDayRange = moment();
    
        let convertedDate = moment().toISOString();
        console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDate);
    
    
        // let convertedDate = moment(setSelectedDayRange).toISOString();
        // console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDate);
    
      
        this.setState({
          selectedDayRange: setSelectedDayRange,
        });
      };
```

[Sandbox URL to mess around with it.](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-edison-h5dxm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: If you're behind UTC it will happen if the dates does not include timestamp. It will assume the given date is at 00:00 UTC, and if you'er in the US (something like UTC-4) it will show as the previous day.

Comment: ok. get that part. I just wish to convert the values of my `setSelectedDayRange` into 
ISO-8601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, if you need just to convert `setSelectedDayRange` to date in `toISOString` you could do:

```
let convertedDateFrom = moment(setSelectedDayRange.from).toISOString();
console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDateFrom);

let convertedDateTo = moment(setSelectedDayRange.to).toISOString();
console.log("setSelectedDayRange", convertedDateTo);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-firefly-h58l4?file=/src/index.js) your code modified.